# Laravel + l5-repository

Tags: laravel

Caros,
estou tentando instalar o l5-repository e dou o comando:

`composer require prettus/l5-repository`

e aparece o seguinte:

```
Using version ^2.6 for prettus/l5-repository
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan ide-helper:generate
A new helper file was written to _ide_helper.php
> php artisan ide-helper:meta
A new meta file was written to .phpstorm.meta.php
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled class file has been removed.
```

Porém quando rodo php artisan, só aparecem estas opções:

```
    make
  make:auth            Scaffold basic login and registration views and routes
  make:command         Create a new Artisan command
  make:controller      Create a new controller class
  make:event           Create a new event class
  make:job             Create a new job class
  make:listener        Create a new event listener class
  make:mail            Create a new email class
  make:middleware      Create a new middleware class
  make:migration       Create a new migration file
  make:model           Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:notification    Create a new notification class
  make:policy          Create a new policy class
  make:provider        Create a new service provider class
  make:request         Create a new form request class
  make:seeder          Create a new seeder class
  make:test            Create a new test class
```

Já coloquei a linha no config\app.php

Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class

E quando vou rodar a linha abaixo, vem o erro:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider"
Nothing to publish for tag [].
```

Não sei mais o que fazer.
Será que conseguem me ajudar ?

Um abraço
Tonico

Comment: Uma dica, não use esse pacote, ele falta explicar alguns detalhes e você acaba fazendo a mesma coisa que já vem pronta no `Laravel`, sinceridade não utilize, se já existe isso pronto no `Laravel` com os próprio `model` `Eloquent`, utilize ele, porque: é muito simples utilizar a validação e as operações com pouca codificação. Já vi alguns pacotes melhores e bem mais simples e que utilizam a base do `Laravel` sem mudar a sua forma de validação que já é bem solida. Se você está preocupado com geradores, não está preocupado em aprender, cuidado.

Comment: Virgilio, obrigado pela dica... Eu só estou usando pois estava em um curso e mostrava como usava. Mas já resolvi o problema. Eu não devo usar mesmo não, devo usar somente o Bootstrapper o PDF.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi,
limpei o composer.json e apaguei a linha no config/app.php.
Instalei seguindo manual de novo e tudo funcionou...

Obrigado por que leu e tentou ajudar...

Um abraço
Tonico